# Execute python cli anywhere while depending on a resource file

Tags: python, resources, command-line-interface

I have a resource that a python cli script is depending on. I want to be able to execute the script anywhere from my machine but since the script is depending on that particular reasons, the script won't work. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the resource is in the same directory as the script, it's easy.

```
scriptdir = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
resource = scriptdir + '/resource.rc'
```

Comment: i tried this however the resource was not included when installing the python package

Comment: You didn't say an installer was involved.  You should mention which installer.  They all have ways to include extra files.